# Retrieving application ID from db2 8.1.5 on Z/OS

Tags: db2, zos

I want to observe application id of current session from db2 8.1.5 on Z/OS but there is not a function which shows the application id in db2 prior to 8.2 . I was not able to find the exact solution. Please can you tell me any solution if there is.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Prior to db2 8.2 you have to write your own function. If you have the DB2 Application Development Client and a C or Java compiler installed you can try the procedure outline [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0302stolze/0302stolze.html)

Comment: I have seen that link before but because i want to get app-id from db2 on Z/OS, it is uncompleted solution for me. To execute user defined function said in the link,workload manager sould be created and udf should be specified with workload manager as i understand. However, i could not find how to do it. If am wrong, can you inform me?

Comment: One more thing i forgot to ask, where should the class file in the link be copied? Client or Server?